# Code Analysis Ruleset for Visual Studio Express for Desktop 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-analysis

Where can I find the set of rules used for code analysis in Visual Studio Express for Desktop 2013?

As I understand it, only a limited ruleset is supported in the Express versions of Visual Studio, but I can't find any documentation as to which rules are applied.

I'm guessing it may be the [Managed Minimun Rules rule set for managed code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh748309.aspx), but the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264925.aspx) is not explicity, only saying:

> These rules are small in number and they are intended only to run in
>   limited Visual Studio editions. Use MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset
>   with other Visual Studio editions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the Express edition can not edit the rule sets, but the rules are supported. *(At least for **Visual Studio 2015 Express**.)*

I edited some rules in the ***Community Edition*** and saved it to project. And after this, these rules were applied even in the ***Express***. Unfortunately I also was not able to find any description.

If you want to add extended rules to project, add/update some lines in project file:

```
<RunCodeAnalysis>true</RunCodeAnalysis>
<CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MyProject.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
```

to your project for all configurations; where the `MyProject` is project name. *(the `RunCodeAnalysis` line should be already there)*

And the MyProject.ruleset file *(example)* is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RuleSet Name="Rules for MyProject" Description="Code analysis rules for MyProject.csproj." ToolsVersion="14.0">
  <IncludeAll Action="Warning" />
  <Rules AnalyzerId="Microsoft.Analyzers.ManagedCodeAnalysis" RuleNamespace="Microsoft.Rules.Managed">
    <Rule Id="CA2210" Action="None" />
    <Rule Id="CA1824" Action="None" />
    <Rule Id="CA1300" Action="None" />
  </Rules>
</RuleSet>
```

This example is based on `AllRules.ruleset` *(when I'm not wrong)*. The example above disables three rules, that should not be reported.

Available Actions are:

- `None` to disable warning,
- `Info` *(seems that it do not work in this example, probably has something to do with the include action type)*,
- `Warning`
- `Error`
- `Hidden`

**EDIT:**

It seems like not all methods _(from Community Edition) are supported in Express Edition. But at least it is still more than the standardly defined rule-set. To address you original question, the list of rule set is not editable, but you can find it in the only file *.ruleset file in the Visual Studio directory *(`c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\Rule Sets\ManagedMinimumRules.ruleset`)*

e.g. [CA1303: Do not pass literals as localized parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms182187.aspx#) is not supported/reported in Express edition.

Answer (score 0):

the ManagedMinimumRules.ruleset can be changed.

disable the readonly file property, use Admin mode to launch text editor and save it
then run Code Analysis again (need not to close VS)

Action.Info and Hidden are not supported

Comment: Thanks for your reply but can you explain the steps or/and add visual help on how to execute then?